# ActionBar and SearchView problems on the Android 2.3.5

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an `ActionBar` implemented as well as a `SearchView` widget in my app. It works just fine on the Nexus 7, HTC Sensation, etc. - anywhere where the Android version is older than 3.0 I believe. But it doesn't run on the phone with the Android 2.3.5.

Is there anyway to "not display" the action bar and other unsupported stuff when the program runs on the old device?

Here is the error log I get when run in on my old device, sorry for the length, don't really understand which bit is useful:

```
09-27 12:15:03.008: I/dalvikvm(824): Failed resolving Lcom/example/stroke/handling/MainActivity; interface 407 'Landroid/widget/SearchView$OnQueryTextListener;'
09-27 12:15:03.008: W/dalvikvm(824): Link of class 'Lcom/example/stroke/handling/MainActivity;' failed
09-27 12:15:03.008: D/AndroidRuntime(824): Shutting down VM
09-27 12:15:03.008: W/dalvikvm(824): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stroke.handling/com.example.stroke.handling.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.stroke.handling.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.stroke.handling-1.apk]
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1743)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.stroke.handling.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.stroke.handling-1.apk]
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1735)
09-27 12:15:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  ... 11 more
```

P.S. I don't want to use ActionBarSherlock!

Comment: Hey! Did anybody gave you a reasonable answer on how to implement Search without ABS?

Comment: Nope. I went for a standard Action Bar, so it is not supported on the earlier android versions

Comment: I don't like to use ABS. I feel that Google will come up with a nicer approach at any moment and it will be less painful if you have used compatibility package and actionbarcompat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oopsie,

> Remaining backward-compatible
>
> If you want to provide an action bar in your application and remain
>   compatible with versions of Android older than 3.0, you need to create
>   the action bar in your activity's layout (because the ActionBar class
>   is not available on older versions).
>
> To help you, the Action Bar Compatibility sample app provides an API
>   layer and action bar layout that allows your app to use some of the
>   ActionBar APIs and also support older versions of Android by replacing
>   the traditional title bar with a custom action bar layout.

Is it the answer to my question?

**Edit:** that sample app is shit.

Comment: yeah, but i though maybe it could just be "omitted" in the older versions?

Comment: you can user `SherlockActionBar` combined with `Android Support Library` this will work on android 1.6 and above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
http://actionbarsherlock.com/
and add support library to your project, then the action bar will work on 1.6 and above

Answer (score 1):

You can check current os version and run code which is supported e.g.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
   //  use api available only in sdk < 11
}else{
   //  use api available in sdk 11
}
```

Comment: Yeah that would be quite handy if the unsupported code didn't comprise most of it

Comment: I don't understand. In this case unsupported code will not run

Answer (score 0):

This is to inform you that, you should use [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for the same. It is very awesome feature/library provided by the John Watson.

And do refer to this [slide share](http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/action-bar-sherlock-tutorial) tutorial. It will definitely help you.

Let me know if you have any further queries regarding Action Bar Sherlock.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`
Then use "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html